# Create duct in dynamo (Revit)

Tags: revit

I have copied the dynamo script from the bloggers to create the duct in revit but it cannot run.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHBnT.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvRfM.png)

Are there any stupid things that I have missed?

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar error because of a missed dependency import.  I also had error trying to select a specific DuctType so I left it blank and the Revit API selects the first one for us. I was able to make it work with a similar approach:

See Dynamo File: [Dynamo Add Duct .dyn image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aa2Jn.png)

```py
import clr

# Import RevitNodes
clr.AddReference("RevitNodes")
import Revit

#import Revit DB
clr.AddReference('RevitAPI')
from Autodesk.Revit.DB import *

#import Revit Creation where Create.Duct is
from Autodesk.Revit.Creation import *
clr.ImportExtensions(Revit.GeometryConversion)

# Import Revit elements
from Revit.Elements import *

# Import DocumentManager
clr.AddReference("RevitServices")
import RevitServices
from RevitServices.Persistence import DocumentManager
from RevitServices.Transactions import TransactionManager

import System

#The inputs to this node will be stored as a list in the IN variables.
doc = IN[0]
x = IN[1].ToXyz()
y = IN[2].ToXyz()
ductType = IN[3]
#ductTypeUnwrapped = UnwrapElement(ductType) #not working

# Start Transaction
TransactionManager.Instance.EnsureInTransaction(doc)
doc.Create.NewDuct(x, y, ductType); #if DuctType is null then Revit picks first type. 
# Stop Transaction
TransactionManager.Instance.TransactionTaskDone()

OUT = doc
```